# Removing duplicates from a result set of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have this request:

```
res = Model1.joins(:items).where(items: {id: [1, 2, 3]})
```

It returns data with duplicates, although there're no duplicates in a database. How to remove duplicates from `res`?

Answer (score 9):

Use [.uniq](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq) in Rails 4 and [.distinct](http://devdocs.io/rails%7E5.0/activerecord/querymethods#method-i-distinct) in Rails 5:

```
res = Model1.joins(:items).where(items: { id: [1, 2, 3] }).uniq
```

or,

```
res = Model1.joins(:items).where(items: { id: [1, 2, 3] }).distinct
```

Comment: This will make an array of objects, it will not be an Active Record relation anymore

Answer (score -1):

An SQL join (using [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins)) gives you the product of two tables. If you're trying to get the `Model1` records that are related to specific `Item` records, then use

```
Model1.where(item_id: [1, 2, 3])
```